# setting value of a property in source list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 2 lists

```
public class EmailDetails
    {
        public int EmailMasterID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string IsModified { get; set; }
      
    }
    public class EmailDetailsActual
    {
        public string ProgramNumber { get; set; }
        public string IsModified { get; set; }
        public int EmailMasterID_FK { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to set value of IsModified column to YES in EmailDetails list if EmailMasterID = EmailMasterID_FK (from EmailDetailsActual list)  . If not, then set value to NO. The final result should be EmailDetails list.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but i put new EmailDetailsActual in EmailDetails and I put the details for that (ProgramNumber , IsModified , EmailMasterID_FK)

and then I put input to when Call EmailDetails , should fill inputs like

```
EmailDetails p1 = new EmailDetails("ProgramNumber", "IsModified", 0000);
```

after i put **IsModified** Get properties in **EmailDetails** >>

```
if (EmailMasterID == EDA.EmailMasterID_FK)
                {
                    return "yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "no";
                }
     // EDA is new EmailDetailsActual
```

And I accessed it values ​​in a this way (accessed EmailMasterID_FK (we create new EmailDetailsActual ) )

---

and its my finally >>>

```
 public class EmailDetails
    {
        EmailDetailsActual EDA = new EmailDetailsActual();

        public EmailDetails(string ProgramNumber , string IsModified , int EmailMasterID_FK)
        {
            EDA.ProgramNumber = ProgramNumber;
            EDA.IsModified = IsModified;
            EDA.EmailMasterID_FK = EmailMasterID_FK;
        }




        public int EmailMasterID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string IsModified { get
            {
                if (EmailMasterID == EDA.EmailMasterID_FK)
                {
                    return "yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "no";
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public class EmailDetailsActual
    {
        public string ProgramNumber { get; set; }
        public string IsModified { get; set; }
        public int EmailMasterID_FK { get; set; }
    }
```

---

this is example to work >>

```
EmailDetails p1 = new EmailDetails("ProgramNumber", "IsModified",9991);

p1.EmailMasterID = 9992;

Console.WriteLine(p1.IsModified);
```

its output `no` bc `EmailMasterID (9991)` its not same with `EmailMasterID_FK(9992)`

I hope I able to help you :)